# General solutions to system of ODEs given b or c or both are 0?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

I have:
$$
x'(t) = ax(t)+by(t) 
$$
$$
y'(t) = cx(t)+dy(t) 
$$
I want to ask whether there is a general solution for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ when b or c is 0 or both are 0? 
 The values of a and d should not be significant. 
Thank you for paying attention to my question!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $b=0$, it's very easy to solve for $x(t)$, isn't it? And once you know $x(t)$, you can insert it into the equation for $y$ and compute $y(t)$.

Comment: But do you think the signs of the solutions would be affected by a and d? I have tried and got different answers for different values of a and d, given that x(t) and y(t) are in R